# Ajax WebMethod approach with javascript calls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am having trouble with running a Javascript program with my online server.  I was thinking that this may be an alternative:

Ajax WebMethod approach with javascript calls:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gettime(){
        var hour = new Date().getHours();
        document.getElementById("hr")=hour;
    }
</script>
```

Asp.net 4.0:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Function HourFromJavascript() As Integer
        printhour='hr from gettime
    End Function
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What's your question? What is the above code supposed to do?

Comment: I am trying to execute a simple javascript program using ajax WebMethod.  I could do it an easier way but I want to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't making any AJAX calls to your server side web method. One of the easiest ways to do that is with [jQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). In addition, it looks like you're trying to get something to the server side from the client, but you need to fully explain what you're trying to accomplish.